# Convert Accelerometer in 3D Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, scenekit, radians

I need to convert the motion from an accelerometer into the appropriate values in order to rotate a SceneKit Object. My code to convert the raw x,y,z values into Radians is:

```
    let theta   : Float = atan2(x, sqrtf(powf(y, 2)+powf(z, 2)))
    let psi     : Float = atan2(y, sqrtf(powf(x, 2)+powf(z, 2)))
    let phi     : Float = atan2(sqrtf(powf(x, 2)+powf(y, 2)), z)
```

I'm struggling to convert this into a full 360 degree angle to rotate the object.

Any help?

Comment: What do you actually want? If you want a 360 degree angle, what do you want it to be around? In the real world you have 360x180 degrees since it's in 3D

Comment: Hi, my explanation maybe a little off as my maths and physics are very old. I have a SceneKit object I wish to rotate relative to the position of an accelerometer (data received by BLE) on its x and y axis. Relative to the Scenekit objects centre mass. So I assume that I need full 360 degrees on x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SceneKit you can use x,y,z euler angles directly:

```
let object:SCNNode = ...
object.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), z: CGFloat(z))
```

Comment: You using the built in accelerometer within iOS. I am using a separate accelerometer accessed over BLE. How do the equations I posted equate to a Quaternion?

Comment: Okay, I changed it to use Euler x,y,z angles.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It works, although I'm not 100% confident that me Euler angle calculations are correct and my model has the same orientation.